# Two- Dimensional Arrays, If.. Else Statement not executing correctly.

Tags: javascript

```
var correct = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var questions = [
    ["How many months are there in a year?", 12 ],
    ["What is my favorite vacation spot?", "Costa Rica"],
    ["How old am I?", 23]
];

for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i ++ ) {
  prompt(questions[i][0]);
}  
if (questions[0][1] === 12 ) {
  print("Correct!");
  correct += 1;
  } else {
    wrong += 1;
  }

if(questions[1][1] === "Costa Rica") {
  print("Correct!");
  correct += 1;
  } else {
    wrong += 1;
  }

if(questions[2][1] === 23) {
  print("Correct!");
  correct += 1;
  } else {
    wrong += 1;
  }



print(wrong);
```

This is a practice quiz that I am making with JavaScript. While I was testing the code out I realized even if I put the wrong answer the code is still executing as correct. I tried with removing the correct answer from the array, but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Well, you're not checking the user input - you're checking the `1` index of each item in the array, which is the answer. So you're always getting 100% - you need to figure out a way to store the user responses.

Comment: It might be better to use an object with properties here rather than a 2D array - see this refactor: https://jsfiddle.net/9am7d8pt/ - didn't post it as an answer since I basically rewrote everything.

Comment: @tymeJV  In the assignment I need to use a 2D array that's the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

```js
var wrong = 0;
var questions = [
  ["How many months are there in a year?", 12, null],
  ["What is my favorite vacation spot?", "Costa Rica", null],
  ["How old am I?", 23, null]
];

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  questions[i][2] = prompt(questions[i][0]);
}

for (i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  if (questions[i][1] != questions[i][2])
    wrong++;
}

console.log("Wrong: ", wrong);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation:

```js
(function() {
  let wrong = 0;
  
  const questions = [
    ["How many months are there in a year?", 12],
    ["What is my favorite vacation spot?", "Costa Rica"],
    ["How old am I?", 23]
  ];
  
  questions.forEach((question, idx, arr) => {
    question.push(window.prompt(question[0]));
    wrong += (question[1] != question[2]) ? 1 : 0;
  });
  
  window.alert(`Wrong: ${wrong}`);
})();
```

Which isn't to say it's more correct.  Just a slightly different approach.

Also, note the use of the "!=" comparison operator, as opposed to "!==".

If you need an explanation of the distinction between the two, see [this MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) page.